# when click on the label checbox is not checking in styled components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

i want when user click on the label checbox is selected (custom) only using styled-component as we can do in css and not using javascript. Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hr2vrx

Answer (score 0):

The label attribute `for` must be `htmlFor`.
https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#htmlfor